# On mobile - horizontal view galery looks better than vertical

Tags: html, css

My gallery on mobile phones looks way worse in vertical position than in horizontal.

```css
  .order-gallery ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.order-gallery ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.order-gallery li {
  flex: 1 33%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.order-gallery li img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.panel-body {
  background: rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.5);
  padding: 15px;
```

```html
<div class="panel-body order-gallery">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img pp-type="imagemodal" pp-imagemodal-src="https://placehold.it/600x400" src="https://placehold.it/200x100">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img pp-type="imagemodal" pp-imagemodal-src="https://placehold.it/600x400" src="https://placehold.it/200x100">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img pp-type="imagemodal" pp-imagemodal-src="https://placehold.it/600x400" src="https://placehold.it/200x100">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img pp-type="imagemodal" pp-imagemodal-src="https://placehold.it/600x400" src="https://placehold.it/200x100">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Horizontal view: https://imgur.com/a/1XrZ07K

Vertical view: https://imgur.com/a/YRD7siT

Comment: what kind of help you need ?

Comment: I would like the images on vertical view to be "bigger"

Comment: Without HTML, CSS isn't very helpful. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: I tried to reproduce this as well as possible, it just appears too small in vertical view on mobile

Comment: reduce `padding` of `li` to `padding: 0 10px` for mobile?

Comment: Worked, removed it - thanks!